# The difference between id<protocol> someObject and NSObject<protocol> *someObject

Tags: ios, protocols, nsobject

There are three kind of protocol implementation:

**The first:**

```
@protocol FirstProtocol
...
@end

@property(nonatomic, weak) id<FirstProtocol> delegate;
```

**The second:**

```
@protocol SecondProtocol<NSObject>
...
@end

@property(nonatomic, weak) id<FirstProtocol> delegate;
```

**The third:**

```
@protocol SecondProtocol
...
@end

@property(nonatomic, weak) NSObject<FirstProtocol> *delegate;
```

I just know the "`<NSObject>` or `NSObject<protocol>`" can let the delegate call NSObject selector.
But I don't know what's the difference between them. And which one is the best Practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making claims about what methods can be called on `delegate`.

In `id<FirstProtocol>`, the only supported methods are ones specified in the `FirstProtocol`.

In `id<SecondProtocol>`, the supported methods are ones specified in `SecondProtocol` and the [`NSObject` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/). This gives you access to `-class`, `-superclass`, `-isEqual:`, `-hash`, `-self`, and all the other methods in the `NSObject` protocol.

In `NSObject<FirstProtocol>`, the object must be a kind of [`NSObject`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/). It has access to `-copy`, `-mutableCopy`, and everything else which depends the `NSObject` class.